# Jest Test suite failed to run

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to add Jest tests to a vanilla JS project. I installed Jest with npm, and created an example test file:

```js
// file example.test.js
const { expect } = require("@jest/globals");
const { test } = require("jest-circus");

const one = 1;

test("example test", () => {
  expect(one).toBe(1);
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
 FAIL  ./example.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:175:18)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.437 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Not sure what might be wrong? I clearly have a test/expect block in the test file. I also tried changing `test` to `it` but that had no effect.

Comment: You are missing your `describe` code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import `test` function from `@jest/globals` package.

```js
const { expect, test } = require('@jest/globals');
```

Comment: This was the right answer. In my case autocomplete tried to import `test` from "jest-circus" when it should have been "@jest/globals".